# Run a script using DBX

Tags: unix, solaris, dbx

I have a script like this 
**script** = GF1_dd_Daemon_Sh PROCESS_NAME=RG INSTANCE=RG PART_ID=1

Inside this there is an executable which is called. When I run this script(**#!/bin/ksh** ) it creates a core dump and using dbx when i analyse the stack trace I cannot get any much info.

Is there any way to run the script using DBX and can trace the point where the executable is creating the core dump.

I am using **SOLARIS.**

Thanks.

**Stack Trace**

```
  (dbx) where
    current thread: t@1
      [1] xercesc_2_6::SAXParser::SAXParser(0xffffffff70b833b8, 0xffffffff70b83480, 0x0, 0x0, 0xffffffff70b833f8, 0xffffffff7d12ccd8), at 0xffffffff7ce22fc0
    =>[2] __SLIP.INIT_D() (optimized), at 0xffffffff70a447b8 (line ~35) in "Parser.h"
      [3] __STATIC_CONSTRUCTOR() (optimized), at 0xffffffff70a46f04 (line ~35) in "Parser.h"
      [4] 0xffffffff70a74718(0xffffffff7f7361b8, 0xffffffff7f738d60, 0x11a340, 0x0, 0xffffffff7f736c60, 0x821), at 0xffffffff70a74718
      [5] call_init(0xffffffff7f736530, 0x1, 0xffffffff70a74618, 0xffdfffff, 0xffffffff7f736c60, 0xffffffffffffffff), at 0xffffffff7f618674
      [6] dlmopen_intn(0xffffffff7ffe6b0c, 0x8, 0x4a, 0x52, 0xffffffff7ffe6b0c, 0xffffffff77800a60), at 0xffffffff7f61df7c
      [7] dlmopen_check(0xffffffff7f7361b8, 0xffffffff7ffe6c18, 0x1, 0xffffffff7f400ef0, 0xffffffff7ffe6b0c, 0x118cc8), at 0xffffffff7f61e0f0
      [8] _dlopen(0xffffffff7ffe6c18, 0x1, 0x1, 0xffffffff7ea56d30, 0x11, 0xffffffff7fffc226), at 0xffffffff7f61e130
      [9] GMF_sfg_ACTIVITY(i_pgmName = ???, i_instance = ???, i_coreReplaceRegister_func_p = ???) (optimized), at 0xffffffff7e926ff0 (line ~200) in "GMF_sfg_ACTIVITY.c"
      [10] GMF_mdg_EXECinit(i_pcProcessName = ???, i_argc = ???, i_argv = ???) (optimized), at 0xffffffff7eb33394 (line ~556) in "GMF_mdg_EXECinit.c"
      [11] GMF_mdg_EXECmain(argc = ???, argv = ???) (optimized), at 0xffffffff7eb25ae8 (line ~163) in "GMF_mdg_EXECfunc.c"
      [12] main(argc = ???, argv = ???) (optimized), at 0x100001eb8 (line ~52) in "GMF_mdg_EXECproc.c"
    (dbx) down
    0xffffffff7ce22fc0: SAXParser+0x0110:   ldx      [%i2], %o3
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside the script check what are the arguments that are being passed to the executable (binary).
2. start the dbx with that executable
3. after it start set the arguments which you have discovered in step 1
4. stop in  GMF_mdg_EXECmain
5. then start checking the code flow

Comment: how to run the executable with dbx ?

Answer (score 0):

One common approach is to add a variable to the script called something like $DEBUGGER

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "this is the script"
$DEBUGGER the_executable arg1 arg2
```

If you set the DEBUGGER environment variable to "dbx", then when you run the script,
dbx will be started and it will give you a dbx prompt.

If you're using the Solaris Studio IDE, you can use "ss_attach" instead of "dbx" and it will attach the debugging session to an IDE that is already running.

Check the man page for ss_attach.